# how to customize a filter for GridView using Search Model?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, gridview, yii2

I'm using a gridview widget in yii2.

in my search view file:

```
$gridview=GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        [
            'attribute'=>'id',
            'width'=>'10%'
        ],
        [
            'attribute'=>'status_id',
            'value'=>function ($data) {
                return $data->statusOption[$data->status_id];
            },
           'filterType'=>GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
           'filter'=> Problem::getStatusOption(),
        ],
        [
            'attribute'=>'content',
        ]
    ]
]);
```

now i've already customized the search model to support filtering the items by multiple status_id as following.

in my ItemSearch Model file:

```
class ItemSearch extends Item
{
    public $sids=[];

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['status_id'], 'integer'],
            [['sids'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    public function query($params)
    {
        $this->load($params);

        $query = Item::find();

        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'status_id' => $this->status_id,
        ]);

        if(!empty($this->sids))
        {
            $query->andWhere(['in','status_id',  $this->sids]);
        }
    }

    public function search($params)
    {
        $query=  $this->query($params);

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 10,
            ],
        ]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

now i put an adidtional select box outside the grid. which is a little ugly with a submit button aside.

in my search view file:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'method' => 'get',
]);?>

<div class="form-group">
    <select class="status" name="ItemSearch[sids][]" multiple="true">
          <option value="0">status 0 </option>
          <option value="1">status 1 </option>
     </select>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">submit</button>
 </div>
```

i store the selected status in an array for js things.

```
echo "var stSelect = ".\yii\helpers\Json::encode($searchModel->sids).";\n"
```

i want to make the following button group work.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
<?php foreach(Problem::getStatusOption() as $key=>$val):?>
    <label class="status-button btn btn-default <?= in_array($key, $searchModel->sids)?"active":''?>" data-key="<?=$key?>"><input type="checkbox"><?= $val?></label>
<?php endforeach;?>
</div>
```

so i write some js using Jquery:

```
$('.status-button').on('click', function(){
    stSelect = toggle(Number($(this).attr("data-key")),stSelect);
    $('.status').val(stSelect);
})

var toggle = function(value,array){
    if(array.indexOf(value) > -1) {
        array.splice(array.indexOf(value),1)
    }else{
        array.push(value)
    }
    return array
}
```

but now i have following problems to handle with:

- everytime i submit the form, the get params send to the controller just simply add to the last params.

  for example, in 1st submit, i select status 0.

  stSelect={"0"}

  in 2rd submit i select status 0 and 1.

  stSelect={"0","0","1"}

  but the original filter works fine.
- i need to click submit to refresh the grid. how to let grid to update when click the button group buttons?